# How to check if request user is in a models class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Lets say you have a class with name Car_club
and in the class is members, which is a manytomany field to the User.

Then you want to limit some part of the page for only members.

```
class Car_club(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, on_delete=CASCADE
```

Lets say in the html there is parts where only the members of that class should see, how to manage that?

### Updated

views.py

```
def car_clubs(request):
    car_clubs = Car_clubs.objects.all()
    team_members = user.Car_club_set.all()
    context = {
        'car_clubs': car_clubs,
        'team_members': team_members,
    }
    return render(request, 'cars.html', context)
```

First what user.Car_club? I can get user from get_user_model, but then i get;

```
Type object 'User' has no attribute 'Car_club_set'?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

team_members is not needed to send via context

```
def car_clubs(request):
    car_clubs = Car_clubs.objects.all()
    context = {
        'car_clubs': car_clubs,
    }
    return render(request, 'cars.html', context)
```

in your template (cars.html):

```
{% for car_club in car_clubs %}
   {% if request.user in car_club.members.all %}
       <p>{{car_club}}</p>
       {% for member in car_club.members.all %}
           <p>{{member}}</p>
       {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

and you get the list of members for club_car, only if the user is in the members of that club.

or if wanna make the limit in view:

```
def car_clubs(request):
    car_clubs = Car_clubs.objects.filter(members__id=request.user.id)
    context = {
        'car_clubs': car_clubs,
    }
    return render(request, 'cars.html', context)
```

this will return onlys the car_clubs that the user is in.